# In Apache Echarts, can inside piechart labels switch automatically to outside if they overlap?

Tags: echarts

I have a nested pie chart (two pie chart series, one an outer "doughnut" around the other). The inner pie chart needs to mainly use inner-positioned labels, but sometimes there isn't enough room and they overlap:

[image]

How can I get this to not overlap? Is there a way to switch the overlapping labels or those that can't fit inside their slices to be outer-positioned instead? Or some other strategy to make these readable? Using 100% outer positioned labels works, but because of the outer pie chart there isn't much room and it's much harder to read because the outer pie chart also has its own set of outer-positioned labels.

Series def:

```
    seriesOpt = [{
      encode: {
        value: "value",
        itemName: "name"
      },
      type: "pie",
      startAngle: 90,
      //minShowLabelAngle: 0.05, // buggy, throws internal javascript error
      avoidLabelOverlap: true,
      datasetIndex: 0,
      name: "inner",
      radius: [0, insideRadius??"40%"],
      label: {
        show: true,
        position: "inside"
        distanceToLabelLine: 10,
        alignTo: "none",
        overflow: "truncate",
        formatter: '{name|{b}}\n{pct|{d}%}',
        rich: {
          pct: {
            color: '#999'
          }
        },
      labelLine: {
        show: false
      }
    },{
      encode: {
        value: "value",
        itemName: "name"
      },
      type: "pie",
      startAngle: 90,
      //minShowLabelAngle: 0.05, // buggy, throws internal javascript error
      avoidLabelOverlap: true,
      datasetIndex: 1,
      name: "outer",
      radius: [outsideInnerRadius??"60%",outsideOuterRadius??"75%"],
      label: {
        show: true,
        position: "outside",
        distanceToLabelLine: 10,
        alignTo: "none",
        overflow: "truncate",
        formatter: '{name|{b}}\n{pct|{d}%}',
        rich: {
          pct: {
            color: '#999'
          }
        },
      labelLine: {
        show: true,
        length: 60,
        length2: 15
    }
  }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should tweak [`series-pie.labelLayout`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie.labelLayout).

Here is an example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    value: 10
  },
  {
    name: 'Bar',
    value: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Baz',
    value: 15
  },
  {
    name: 'Qux',
    value: 500
  }
];

let option = {
  series: [
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: ['120px', '90px'],
      center: ['50%', '50%'],
      data,
      label: {
        position: 'inner'
      },
      labelLayout: {
        moveOverlap: 'shiftY' // <--- HERE
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'pie',
      radius: '42px',
      center: ['50%', '50%'],
      data,
      label: {
        position: 'inner'
      },
      labelLine: {
        showAbove: true
      },
      // ========== THERE ==========
      labelLayout: {
        x: 131,
        moveOverlap: 'shiftY'
      }
      // ====================
    }
  ]
};

let myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```css
#main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main"></div>
```